# How can I generate dynamic url in a list?

Tags: html, vue.js, dictionary, frontend

I get a list from my backend:

```
[
{
'name': 'nameA',
'codename': 'codenameA'
},
{
'name': 'nameB',
'codename': 'codenameB'
},
{
'name': 'nameC',
'codename': 'codenameC'
}
```

My goal is to display a list of owner.name with a url like `http://myurl/owner/edit/${{ owner.codename }}` using VueJS.

Currently my code is :

```
<template>
<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <ul v-for="owner in this.databaseOwners" :key="owner.name" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href=`"localhost:8080/admin/owner/${{{ owner.codename }}}"` target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">{{ owner.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

But it doesn't work, how can I use dynamic URL in my case? I'm really new to frontend so I'm sorry if my question seems really trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Make a new method under `methods` property of your Vue component:

```
methods: {
    url(codename) {
        return `/admin/owner/${codename}`;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<a :href="url(owner.codename)">...</a>
```

Pay attention to the colon symbol:

```
:href
```

It means that it will try and bind the href attribute to some variable/method/computed property that is coming from the Vue component

Answer (score 1):

This works : `<a :href="'/admin/owner/' + owner.codename">{{ owner.name }}</a>`

Comment: Yes, this works as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

this may work

```
<a :href="'localhost:8080/admin/owner/'+owner.codename " target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">{{ owner.name }}</a>
```

Comment: It raises a syntax error `invalid expression: Unexpected token '{' in 'localhost:8080/admin/owner/'+{{ owner.codename }}`

Comment: curly braces had to be removed